# How to migrate default user data to custom user model in Django

Tags: django

As I want to customize Django user model, I migrated from default user model to my own custom user model. Since my Django project has been working since a long time ago, I need to keep the existing user data.

I was thinking to move them manually, but Django default user model's passwords are hidden. How can I safely move existing user data to my custom user model?

Comment: Is your field are same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving to `CustomUser` is [no easy task in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project). If you want to keep the existing data, then as per ticket [#25313](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25313), you need to do the following steps:

1. Create a custom user model identical to `auth.User`, call it User (so many-to-many tables keep the same name) and set `db_table='auth_user'` (so it uses the same table).
2. Throw away all your migrations from all the apps(except for `__init__.py` file inside the migrations folder).
3. Recreate a fresh set of migrations(using `python manage.py makemigrations`).
4. Make a backup of your database.
5. Delete all entries from **django_migrations** table from DB.
6. Fake-apply the new set of migrations(using `python manage.py migrate --fake`).
7. Optional: Set `db_table="your_custom_table"` or remove it altogether.
8. Make other changes to the custom model, generate migrations, apply them.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed steps! For deleting all migrations, can you explain why I need to throw away all migrations? After finishing by step 2, I can see my custom user model shows up with my existing user data. From that point, I just wanna make sure if it's a necessary step.

Comment: When you run migration with new updated fields, you might see this error *ValueError: Related model ‘app.User’ cannot be resolved*. So to prevent that, you need take these steps. You can check this blog as well: https://ruddra.com/posts/django-custom-user-migration-mid-phase-project/

Answer (score 0):

You can dump your existing model data with dumpdata command and also able to reload those data to that model or your changed custom model with loaddata command. Here is a good example how you can able to do that. [link](https://coderwall.com/p/mvsoyg/django-dumpdata-and-loaddata)